# Error 9 subscript out of range when opening workbook by name

Tags: excel, vba

I built a database out of a couple of workbooks and some VBA-code. The database runs without any problem on all computers except for one. If I run the following basic VBA code I get error 9 (subscript out of range):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("User Interface").Sheets("Start").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

If I add `MSGbox "you openend the following Workbook: " & ActiveWorkbook.name` to the code like:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MSGbox "you openend the following workbook: " & ActiveWorkbook.name
Workbooks("User Interface").Sheets("Start").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It returns the messagebox with the text "you openend the following Workbook: User Interface.xlsm", but also returns the "subscript out of range" error on line
`Workbooks("User Interface").Sheets("Start").Activate`.

I guess the Excel file isn't able to find or recognize itself.

Perhaps it has something to do with the settings in office, virus scanner, or windows. The computers run either office 365 and office 2016. The computer that returns error 9 does also runs office 365 (on windows 10).

Edit#1:

@ Bigben: I'm gonna have a look if changing the file extension setting solves the problem. If this works, I guess I gonna go lazy and put an on error statement in the code with somthing like:
`MSGbox "Error 9: Go and change youre File explorer settings."`

How the database is built:
The file User Interface.xlsm is opened by hand. `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` starts to run to assign a temporary username and open the menu (via frmstart.show).

The database in concept:
I use the file User Interface to load and write data from and to the database.
The file User Interface has it own folder With subfolder "Data". In the folder "Data" I put a couple of different files (data files). When a user clicks on "write to database" in the User Interface, the following code will be activated:

```
Set closedbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data\" & Datafile & ".xlsm")
```

There are 11 datafiles in the folder data.

Comment: The problem is the extension `.xlsm`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935543/file-directory-issues-with-subscript-out-of-range-error). Do you open this workbook programmatically? Can you share more of your code? There's probably a workaround to referring to the workbook by name.

Comment: See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `Activate` a worksheet unless the Workbook is first activated, so

```
Workbooks("User Interface.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Start").Activate
```

Also you cannot `Activate` or `Select` a range unless the  worksheet parenting that range is  active.

**EDIT#1:**

If you create a workbook Object when the workbook is opened, you don't need to resolve *"User Interface"* vs *"User Interface.xlsm"*

```
Sub dural()
    Dim UI As Workbook
    Set UI = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="User Interface.xlsm")
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    UI.Activate
    Sheets("Start").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I get this POV but why would it work on some computers and not others?

Comment: @jamheadart - because of the extension, as I already mentioned in the comment above.