# Excel Document Causing Runtime error on one PC not others

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba code in the ThisWorkbook excel object. The code runs before closing the document. On all other PCs It runs perfectly. On my current pc it is causing a runtime error. What can cause this difference?

See Code Below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim iStatus As Long
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks("WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm")
iStatus = Err
On Error GoTo 0
If iStatus Then 'workbook isn't open

Else
   'workbook is open
   Workbooks("WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: And the error message is? And what line throws it?

Comment: Sorry I tried adding it above but it made me remove it. It says Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range. When I opened and closed the same exact document on 3 other pcs I had no problem at all. The error line is 'Set wb = Workbooks("WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm")'.

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935543/file-directory-issues-with-subscript-out-of-range-error).

Comment: That did not solve the issue. I tried with extension, without extension, and full filepath.

Comment: Maybe you should then loop over all the `Workbooks` collection and print out the name of each workbook, and compare to the name you're currently using.

Comment: Note that you can just test `If Not wb Is Nothing` - perhaps a bit simpler.

Comment: Regardless the actual workbook is not open. So I don't know why it's still erroring. I also tried with the database open and still have the same error. But on other pcs. No problem. I'm going to uninstall and reinstall. Online repair failed.

Comment: Well looks like excel corrupted my profile. I had to make a new one. The issue is no longer a problem. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

`On Error Resume Next` will not prevent an error message it you've set your Excel VBA error handling to "Break On All Errors".

Resetting your profile may have fixed that setting.